# USPS shipping not showing Magento version 1.9.1

Tags: magento-1.9, shipping, fedex, ups, usps

I know this question has been asked several times for different versions of magento but still I cannot find the relevant information and answer. Many of the users haven't marked the comments as answer. Well if still you find this question irrelevant or repetitive you can mark it as close but please guide me in right direction.
Well I just finished my very first site using magento version 1.9.1 but I'm getting an error for the USPS and UPS shipment module.

[image]

I've tried every thing. I tried changing my zip code to zip4, I double rechecked my credentials, I checked on live and development mode, I checked on my localhost and on live site also, I changed the weight of the products also but nothing worked.

[image]

[image]

[image]

There is nothing in the error log that is var/log file.

Please help me friends. Thank you.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed the issue. Searched the entire Google. I adjusted the min and max weights allowed. I changed the weights for the products. I changed the mode for shipment. I also changed the shipping settings. I changed the zip code and address. All these changes worked for. Hope some one would find this useful.

Comment: In my debug.log I have this error -   'result' => 
  array (
    'error' => 'Unable to read response, or response is empty',
    'code' => 0,
  ), Can you help me in this pls??